# php class private variable not accessable

Tags: php

I am trying to write a php class, there is a variable call $ENV, I can access it it the constructor, however, I can't echo it in the connect method. Any thought?

```
<?php 
class DB_Connection {

    private $ENV        = 'production';
    private $conn_staus = '';

    public function __construct() {
        echo $ENV;
    }

    public function connect() {
        echo $ENV;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use the object accessor operator `echo $this->ENV`

Answer (score 2):

You have to access it using $this->ENV:

```
<?php 
class DB_Connection {

    private $ENV        = 'production';
    private $conn_staus = '';

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->ENV;
    }

    public function connect() {
        echo $this->ENV;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why in constructor they work?

Comment: never mind, they won't work if there is no $this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class DB_Connection {

    private $ENV        = 'production';
    private $conn_staus = '';

    public function __construct() {
        echo $ENV;
    }

    public function connect() {
        echo $ENV;
    }
}
```

There is one minor thing, you should call internal variables by using `$this->` so:

```
public function __construct(){
  echo $this->ENV;
}
```

[PHP $this variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494436/php-this-variable)   The following Stackoverflow Question link should explain more.