# Unable to pass variable from function to class

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

I have a db connect function and an abstract database class bause of the way I structure it. I have to keep added my PDO connect codes to the constructor.

My config.php I have

```
function dbconnect() 
{
            $dbh; // database handler
             $host = 'localhost';
             $user =  'root';
             $pass =  '';
             $dbname = 'test101';
             $error;
                // Set DSN
                $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
                // Set options
                $options = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false

                );
                // Create a new PDO instanace
                try{
                    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
                }
                // Catch any errors
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                }

           }
```

in my abstract.class.php

```
 include_once('config/config.php');

class Database {


           public function __construct() {
               dbconnect(); //connect to database

           }

           public function query($query) {
               $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
           }

}
$database = New Database();
```

not in config.php I have a dtabase handler `$dbh` and in abstract.class.php I am calling its in the query function.

**My question**

I am getting an error `Undefined property: Database::$dbh`. how can I pass this from my config.php to abstract.class.php?  I thought when you using the PHP include this is the same as copying and paste whatever is in that file in the file you want to use it for. How can I pass `$dbh` from config.php to abstract.class.php please feel free to advice me on anything issues that might happen, or anything with my PDO connection that will do with security issues.

This works if I copy and pass my function in the constructor and set the database connection variables to `private $dbh;` outside the constructor but the issue with this is the fact of always having to include the class when I dont every need it. sometimes I might just need to connect to the database also I wanted to add `define salt` to the config.php

Comment: What do you think `__construct` function defined inside `dbconnect` function would do?

Comment: @zerkms sorry forgot to edit that part when I copy the codes over

Comment: the question is still open. They are just 2 nested functions.

Comment: what is the purpose of having `__construct` function inside a `dbconnect` function?

Comment: Okay, you removed it. Now you're using `$this->` in your function. What it supposed to mean?

Comment: So what `$this->` in your function definition means?

Comment: as @zerkms said, You are misusing $this, you can only use that when working inside a class: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494436/php-this-variable

Comment: it is means to point to the function itself or does this only work with functions which are in a class

Comment: @user3057514: it points to the *current object*

Comment: @user3057514 , You can only do that from within classes, just say $dbh = new PDO(...); same for the error

Comment: thanks @Mazzy for the link and @zerkrns. I replace all `$this` with included the onces in $dns` but I am still facing this error `Notice: Undefined variable: dbh` I have also replace remove `this->` in the abstract class. but I am

Comment: @user3057514 in your database class you are calling $this->dbh, but, dbh doesn't exist in that class, so in your dbconnect function, return $dbh, then assign $this->dbh = dbconnect();

Comment: @Mazzy thanks a million. I have rate you. If you can but this in an answer i will tick it off thanks again for your time

Comment: @Mazzy in terms of security how secure do you think the PDO connection is?

Comment: @user3057514 The connection will be secure that's not the problem, the security issue will be with SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database class you are calling $this->dbh, so in your dbconnect function,
`return $dbh`, then in the database class constructor: `$this->dbh = dbconnect();`